Can I mount a specific partition from an image file?
Say I have an .iso file from this dd command:
dd if=/dev/sda of=./image.iso

In the case where the drive contained multiple partitions, how could I say, only mount the second one?

See in particular losetup -P in the answers to the linked question.

The file name image.iso seems to be misleading. An ISO image is usually an image of a CD or DVD. /dev/sda is probably a disk, SSD or USB pendrive.
